# Растягивание родителя по высоте дочернего блока с абсолютным позиционированием

Tags: html, css

Есть родительский блок с `position:relative` который содержит дочерний блок с `position: absolute`. Есть ли возможность средствами CSS растянуть родителя по высоте дочернего?

Answer (score 2):

CSS средствами этого сделать нельзя, так как их взаимосвязь не физическая, эту проблему можно решить JS:

```
<div class='first'>
  <div class='second'>

  </div>
```

```
$(".first").height($(".second").height()); 
$(".first").width($(".second").width());
```

Comment: Есть ли возможность средствами CSS растянуть родителя по высоте дочернего? (c) Вырезка из вопрос. Из чего должен следовать ответ: Нет, нельзя средствами css это сделать.